# Changing background and font color for alternate menus with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have an App made with jQuery Mobile that has a list view for menu items.  I would like to alternate the background colors for the menu items, and maybe change the font color in conjunction with that.

I've seen suggestions to do this with jQuery, but I don't think that it works because I am using jQuery Mobile and it heavily modifies the DOM.  The menus are of this format, a list view in my code:

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li> <a href="#about">About 4 Verses</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#subjects">Subjects</a></li>
        <li> <a href= "#promises">God Promises</a></li>
        <li> <a href= "#prayerHelp">Prayer Help</a></li>
        <li> <a href= "#living">Living a Christian Life</a></li>
        <li> <a href= "#information">Information</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why CSS wouldn't work in this case? `li { background: red; }` with `li:nth-child(odd) { background: black; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with this CSS (background and font color supported).

```
li:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: black; 
}

li > a { color: black }
li:nth-child(odd) > a {
    color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kz0m5we6/

Comment: That doesn't work, I think because of jQuery Mobile and the way it modifies the DOM.  If I can programatically change/add data-theme="b" for every other list item, i.e. odd that would probably work.  Is there a way to add that as an attribute for every other list item using jQuery?

Comment: $('ul li:nth-child(odd)').attr('data-theme', 'b');

by adding the data-theme="b" to odd list elements are the DOM has loaded, but I would have to find a way to refresh the list because jQuery Mobile has already rendered the page.

Comment: That actually does work if I put it in javascript at the end of the page rather than document.ready.  jQuery Mobile must not do its work until after the page is loaded.  Is there a way to customize the data-themes ?  I don't like black and white, I would prefer blue.

Comment: Oups didn't know it was on jquery mobile.